# How connect Typescript with Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have some typescript files, which I want use in me Node.js project. How I can connect this files to use in my Node.js project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Node.JS project isn't made with Typescript, you should do that first. Here is great Example for how to use Typescript with Node.JS https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can compile TypeScript files into JavaScript pretty easily.

Some things you will need to do:

- Install typescript on your project: `npm install --save-dev typescript`.
- Create a `tsconfig.json` file on the root directory to manage the compiler configuration.
- Include a typescript compilation step in your development and build scripts: `tsc <path_to_typescript_files/**/*.ts`

There might be other steps that can streamline your workflow depending on the specifics of your codebase.